# Yii2: Kartik/PopoverX binding to custom button function

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, kartik-v

I am using `yii2 + kartik gridview + popoverx` on each field, want to make a custom button (as a label for example) when clicking on it the textarea fills some comment like <kbd>Buy only at discount</kbd>

[image: Like on image below]

Where can I place that code (of the button), in which file or maybe config from Kartik popover in gridview

```
<span onclick="placeDiscText()"
class="label label-info pull-left"
style="margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 3px; cursor:pointer;">
Buy only at discount.
</span>
```

And the main question what I should place in my placeDiscText() function in JS...

I think something like that

```
$(this).parent()
.find('div.popover-body.popover-content > div.kv-editable-content > form.kv-editable-form > div.kv-editable-parent.form-group > textarea.form-control.kv-editable-input')
.val('Buy only at discount');
```

but it didn't work, I'm just studying JS, please don't laugh if that may be stupid code)

There is no specific indication that this should be span to click, there may be a link, a button, anything, the main thing is to implement such a function.

Comment: where is your code that you used to make the popover ? add the relevant code

Comment: what are you doing , you initially asked for the PopoverX and now after Edit you have added the Editable column , this does not work like this ,if your problem for the Popoverx is solved you should mark the answer and then create another post , this is simply not the way you use the community

Comment: ok, sorry, I think this popover and popover in editable are the same...

Comment: nopes they are not you should create a new question for it i will see into it too, just add the link to the new question here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105068/custom-button-in-editablecolumn-popover-in-kartik-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you havent added the code for the Popover extension you are using so that i could suggest the exact code but as far as i understood you want to add a custom button to the left footer section of the popover modal and for that you need to use the `footer` option. You can provide your string for the HTML to be rendered and thats it. You already have 2 buttons defined which already will be in the footer section so add the following string in the start of that option

```
'<div class="pull-left">'.Html::button('Buy', ['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-info']).'</div>'
```

Your full code for the Popover should look like below.

```
<?php 
echo \kartik\popover\PopoverX::widget([
    'header' => 'Hello world',
    'size'=> \kartik\popover\PopoverX::SIZE_LARGE,
    'placement' => \kartik\popover\PopoverX::ALIGN_RIGHT,
    'content' => Html::textarea('message','Buy only at discount',['id'=>'description'])  ,
    'footer' => '<div class="pull-left">'.Html::button('Buy', ['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-info']).'</div>'.Html::button('Cancel', ['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-danger']).Html::button('Download', ['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-primary']),
    'toggleButton' => ['label'=>'Right', 'class'=>'btn btn-default'],
]);
?>
```

**EDIT**

As you are trying to bind the click to the button inside the modal button so that it inserts a certain text say "Buy only at discount". If you look into the [**`documentation`**](http://demos.krajee.com/popover-x) page of PopOverX there is an example of login button that opens a login form in the modal window and when clicking on submit it submit the form, that submission on click is `javascript` based and looking into the source via your inspector you will see

[image]

Yes inline `onclick` attribute is used to run the `javascript`, you can see the **`advanced HTML content (forms) with popover footer`** section for details on the documentation page, so what you need to do is add like below

```
'<div class="pull-left">'.
  Html::button('Buy', [
    'class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-info',
    'onclick'=>'$("#description").val("Buy only at discount")'
  ])
.'</div>'
```

So your complete code for PopoverX will look like

```
<?php 
echo \kartik\popover\PopoverX::widget([
    'header' => 'Hello world',
    'size'=> \kartik\popover\PopoverX::SIZE_LARGE,
    'placement' => \kartik\popover\PopoverX::ALIGN_RIGHT,
    'content' => Html::textarea('message','Buy only at discount',['id'=>'description'])  ,
    'footer' => '<div class="pull-left">'.
      Html::button('Buy', [
        'class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-info',
        'onclick'=>'$("#description").val("Buy only at discount")'
      ])
    .'</div>'.Html::button('Cancel', ['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-danger']).Html::button('Download', ['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-primary']),
    'toggleButton' => ['label'=>'Right', 'class'=>'btn btn-default'],
]);
?>
```

Comment: Added code in 1st post, it's Editable column, I want to make button, 
сlicking on which, the text ('Buy only at discount') is automatically inserted into the textarea replacing the all text are located there, no more actions, other buttons leave unchanged standard, as now. 
A kind of quick input so you do not write with your hands 'By only at.... etc